# How to transform Python 3 script to Mac OS application bundle?

Tags: python, macos

Is there currently a way to create an application bundle from Py3k script? py2app uses Carbon package and therefore, as far as I understand, cannot be ported to py3k - Carbon development was terminated.

Comment: Carbon support has nothing to do with it. It's just taken a while to get `py2app` and its dependencies updated for Python 3.  The current version of `py2app` supports both Python 2 and Python 3.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not checked if that's true, but [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) 4.1 claims to support Python 3.1 (`cx_freeze` in general has long supported Mac OS X, as well as Windows and Linux, and I believe that also applies to the recent 4.1 release).

Comment: Thank you Alex, it seems to be working somehow (but not from clean installation though - needs manual patching like replacing ldd calls by otool and so on).

Answer (score 1):

There's always Platypus and PyObjC

http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus

http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net

Comment: Thanks, but Platypus does not work with GUI-showing scripts, and pyobjc is mac-specific, while I need some tool like py2app to create platform-specific bundles from crossplatform scripts (in my case, Python + PyQt).